# Definition of n-generated

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

A question from Roman’s *Advanced linear algebra*:

Here is the definition of n-generated:

[image]

And here’s a theorem about it:

[image]

I don’t think Th 5.8 2) is correct if the definition  of n-generated set doesn’t admit multiset ( i.e.  we can’t count the duplicate elements ). For otherwise if we consider the module being **finite field over itself**, we sometimes even can’t have enough elements to be the elements of its submodule, needless to say it being n-generated.

Help and thanku very much!

Comment: Yeah, the definition is bad. It should be $M$ is $n$-generated if there is an $x_1,\dots,x_n$ which generate $M.$ So yes, multi sets are allowed.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much.